# How to set custom Partitioner for kafka in Flink 1.14.3?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

```
    val mySink = KafkaSink.builder()
  .setBootstrapServers(bootstrapserver)
  .setKafkaProducerConfig(myproperties)
  .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
      .setRecordSerializer(
        new mycustomSerializer(mytopic,
                schemaregistryurl)

      ).build()

class mycustomSerializer(topic: String, schemaRegistryUrl: String) extends 
KafkaRecordSerializationSchema[MyRecord]
```

Although the above code is working fine but i am unable to set the custom partitioner in above code

I have gone through the documentation if we make mycustomSerializer using KafkaRecorderSerializationSchema.builder()
then we can set easily but how to do that in above code ?

Comment: I'm not very sure what's the problem here, I just heard about custom practitioner just today. I guess this may help https://dzone.com/articles/custom-partitioner-in-kafka-using-scala-lets-take

Answer (score 0):

The serializer shouldn't set the partitioner.

Inside of `myproperties` map, you should be able to set `ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG` key with the value of your custom class.